# gcloud `BackendConfig` overwrites cookie key set in load balancer, using `--cache-key-include-named-cookie`

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

### Current `BackendConfig`

```yaml
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: foobar
spec:
  timeoutSec: "{{ timeout_sec }}"
  cdn:
    enabled: true
    cachePolicy:
      includeHost: true
      includeProtocol: true
      includeQueryString: true
      queryStringWhitelist: []
    defaultTtl: "{{ caching_ttl }}"
    maxTtl: "{{ caching_ttl }}"
    clientTtl: "{{ caching_ttl }}"
  healthCheck:
    requestPath: /healthz
  sessionAffinity:
    affinityType: "NONE"
    affinityCookieTtlSec: 86400
```

### Setting cookie to be included in cache key

It's currently not possible to set a cookie to be used as part of the cache key, using the `CRD`. We are currently executing the following command after each deployment.

```bash
gcloud compute backend-services update {REDACTED} --cache-key-include-named-cookie='FOOBAR' --global
```

After running the command, we can confirm, that the `Cache key` is present in the CDN configuration in the Google Cloud Console.

After `5m` the configuration is reset to `Default (include all components of a request URL)`.

### Presumption

- `BackendConfig` notified CDN of configuration, and overwrites the `Cache key` configuration.

### Further information

- Was previously not an issue on Kubernetes `1.24.xxx` (current version `v1.26.13-gke.1144000`)

### Question?

How can we configure the `Cache key` configuration, to consider a particular cookie key, in combination with the CRD `cloud.google.com/v1` `BackendConfig`

Answer (score 1):

### What solved the issue

- Removing the `cachePolicy` object from the `BackendConfig`

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: foobar
spec:
  timeoutSec: "{{ timeout_sec }}"
- cdn:
-   enabled: true
-   cachePolicy:
-     includeHost: true
-     includeProtocol: true
-     includeQueryString: true
-     queryStringWhitelist: []
-   defaultTtl: "{{ caching_ttl }}"
-   maxTtl: "{{ caching_ttl }}"
-   clientTtl: "{{ caching_ttl }}"
  healthCheck:
    requestPath: /healthz
  sessionAffinity:
    affinityType: "NONE"
    affinityCookieTtlSec: 86400
```

### Why did this solve the issue?

It appears that when no configuration is set, the configuration in the console is left untouched (we were using the default configuration anyway). This allowed us to configure the cookie key in the cache key with

```bash
gcloud compute backend-services update {REDACTED} --cache-key-include-named-cookie='FOOBAR' --global
```

### Some notes

It looks like the periodic syncing of the `BackendConfig` is how the resource is designed to work. Something must previously have been broken in the old GKE Kubernetes version we were on.